# Google forms input validation for addresses

Tags: google-forms

I was wondering if there's a way for me to **validate the input** of a Google forms to ensure **that it's a valid zip-code**?
I have a list with all the valid zip-codes, so validation from a list is also fine.

Would really appreciate any help (as I've spent much time of my life trying to figure this out).

Comment: For example, how about using regex? https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3378864?hl=en But I'm not sure about your zip-codes you want to use. So I cannot propose the regex. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `Response Validation` option

[image]

In the field you can add the list of your zip-codes separated by the `|` sign enclosed in parenthesis.

```
(1234|2134|3214)
```